# Gridview OnItemClick to play audio

Tags: android, media-player, android-gridview, onitemclicklistener

I want to make an e-learning android application.
I set the string data from database to a gridview item. But I want to set the onitemclick to play an audio from raw folder for every item, that contains about 40 data.
How to set that?

this is my code :

```
public class DaftarHuruf extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private GridView gv;
Cursor cursor;
DBHelper dbHelper;
ListAdapter list_adapter;
String audio;
MediaPlayer mp;

public DaftarHuruf() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater,
        ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daftarhuruf,
            viewGroup, false);

    gv = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    dbHelper.open();

    cursor = dbHelper.getDataHuruf();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    SimpleCursorAdapter list_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.grid_item, cursor,
            new String[] { "huruf", "romanisasi" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.hurufHangeul, R.id.romawi });
        gv.setAdapter(list_adapter);

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            audio =  getString(R.id.hurufHangeul);
            audio.replaceAll(".MP3", "");
            int i;
             i = getResources().getIdentifier(audio, "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());         
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), i);
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data suara tidak ada",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });



    return view;

}

public static DaftarHuruf newInstance(int i) {
    DaftarHuruf frag = new DaftarHuruf();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to randomly play a sound from the raw folder?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
audio =  getString(R.id.hurufHangeul);
        audio.replaceAll(".MP3", "");
        int i;
         i = getResources().getIdentifier(audio, "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());         
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), i);
```

With:

`mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.*name of the audio file*);`

to set up the media player to the specified sound.